# Adding element in middle of xml using xslt

Tags: xslt

Below is the actual xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<employee>
 <Name>ABC</Name>
 <Dept>CS</Dept>
 <Designation>sse</Designation>
</employee>
```

And i want the output as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<employee>
 <Name>ABC</Name>
  <Age>34</Age>
 <Dept>CS</Dept>
  <Domain>Insurance</Domain>
 <Designation>sse</Designation>
</employee>
```

Is this possible to add XML element in between using xslt? 
Please give me sample!

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Here is an XSLT 1.0 stylesheet that will do what you asked:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
   <!-- Identity transform -->
   <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="Name">
      <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
      <Age>34</Age>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="Dept">
      <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
      <Domain>Insurance</Domain>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Obviously the logic will vary depending on where you will be getting the new data from, and where it needs to go. The above stylesheet merely inserts an `<Age>` element after every `<Name>` element, and a `<Domain>` element after every `<Dept>` element.

(Limitation: if your document could have `<Name>` or `<Dept>` elements within other `<Name>` or `<Dept>` elements, only the outermost ones will have this special processing. I don't think you intend for your document to have this kind of recursive structure, so it wouldn't affect you, but it's worth mentioning just in case.)

Comment: What if you only want the element to be added once, instead of once for every Name/Dept elements?

Comment: @Joe: Wow, almost 5 years later. :-) In that case you add the result element in a template that will only match once. E.g. `match="/*/Name[1]"`.

Comment: Excellent, I didn't really expect an answer 5 years later, much less one so prompt!  That helps a lot

Comment: What if I want to pass age (34) as a parameter? I don't want to hard-coded 34 in the xslt file.

Comment: @GLP: It depends on where you want to pass it from. I would recommend creating a new question.

Answer (score 5):

I have modified few things in the existing stylesheet ,it will allow you to choose the specific element and update in your xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
   <!-- Identity transform -->
   <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="Name[1]">
      <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
      <Age>34</Age>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="Dept[1]">
      <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
      <Domain>Insurance</Domain>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<employee>
 <Name>ABC</Name>
 <Dept>CS</Dept>
 <Designation>sse</Designation>
 <Name>CDE</Name>
 <Dept>CSE</Dept>
 <Designation>sses</Designation>
</employee>
```