# XSLT - Add new element at a specific location

Tags: xslt

I'm new to XSLT and I don't know how to accomplish the following.

Below is a part of a xbrl document, generated by another program. Via XSLT, I would like to add an extra element at the position of my comment line:

```
<xbrli:context id="ctx1">
[...]
</xbrli:context>
//Insert a new element here!
<bd-ob-tuple:TaxData>
[...]
</bd-ob-tuple:TaxData>
```

At that location, I would like to add the following element using XSLT:

```
<xbrli:unit id="EUR">
  <xbrli:measure>iso4217:EUR</xbrli:measure>
</xbrli:unit>
```

So that the final result will be:

```
<xbrli:context id="ctx1">
[...]
</xbrli:context>
<xbrli:unit id="EUR">
  <xbrli:measure>iso4217:EUR</xbrli:measure>
</xbrli:unit>
<bd-ob-tuple:TaxData>
[...]
</bd-ob-tuple:TaxData>
```

(The `xbrli:context` element has only one occurence in the whole document, so that perhaps makes it easier to locate the mentioned position for the new element?)

Is there a way I can accomplish this via XSLT?

Comment: What's the defining point of the new element? Can you insert it after every "xrbli:context" element or only between "xrbli:context" and "bd-ob-tuple:TaxData"?

Comment: Apart from that, see this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3649195/adding-element-in-middle-of-xml-using-xslt

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for a complete, simple and short solution that uses the most fundamental XSLT design pattern -- using and overriding the identity rule.

Comment: Randy, Please, *accept* the best answer (by clicking the check-mark next to the answer).

Answer (score 2):

**This transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:xbrli="some:xbrli" exclude-result-prefixes="xbrli">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*" name="identity">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="xbrli:context">
  <xsl:call-template name="identity"/>
  <xbrli:unit id="EUR">
     <xbrli:measure>iso4217:EUR
     </xbrli:measure>
  </xbrli:unit>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the following XML document** (cleaning and wrapping the provided text to make it well-formed):

```
<t xmlns:xbrli="some:xbrli" xmlns:bd-ob-tuple="some:bd-ob-tuple">
    <xbrli:context id="ctx1"> [...] </xbrli:context>
    <bd-ob-tuple:TaxData> [...] </bd-ob-tuple:TaxData>
</t>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result**:

```
<t xmlns:bd-ob-tuple="some:bd-ob-tuple" xmlns:xbrli="some:xbrli">
    <xbrli:context id="ctx1"> [...] </xbrli:context>
    <xbrli:unit id="EUR">
        <xbrli:measure>iso4217:EUR
     </xbrli:measure>
    </xbrli:unit>
    <bd-ob-tuple:TaxData> [...] </bd-ob-tuple:TaxData>
</t>
```

**Explanation**: Use of the identity rule, overriden for `xbrli:context` .

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl"
    xmlns:xbrli="http://xbrli" xmlns:bd-ob-tuple="http://bd-ob-tuple" >
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
        </xsl:copy>
        <xsl:if
            test="local-name() = 'context' and namespace-uri() = 'http://xbrli'">
            <xbrli:unit id="EUR">
                <xbrli:measure>iso4217:EUR</xbrli:measure>
            </xbrli:unit>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: It will work, but it goes against the XSLT idiom, which is to drive conditional processing from the match patterns in the template rules. It's easy for conditional processing inside the template rules to get out of hand and lead to a maintenance nightmare.

Comment: Also, if you're going to do it that way, test="self::xbrli:context" is much better than string comparisons on the local name and namespace URI.