# How to create a XML <counts> element with sub-elements that count other element's occurence?

Tags: xml, xslt

It's two queries but both similar (I think) and both involve counting or subtracting values from elements.

I need process the **sample input file** below so that elements marked with `<!-- must be counted -->` get counted and that the elements `<fpage>` and `<lpage>` get subtracted. The counts and subtraction should then create a `<counts>` element like illustrated on the **expected output file** below.

**Problem:** needs to get done using xslt version 1.0

**sample input file:**

```xml
<article>
    <front>
    <article-meta>
        <fpage>100</fpage> <!-- first page -->
        <lpage>117</lpage> <!-- last page -->
    </article-meta>
    </front>
    <body>
        <table-wrap></table-wrap> <!-- must be counted -->
        <fig></fig> <!-- must be counted -->
        <fig></fig> <!-- must be counted -->
        <disp-formula></disp-formula> <!-- must be counted -->
    </body>
    <back>
        <ref-list>
            <ref></ref> <!-- must be counted -->
            <ref></ref> <!-- must be counted -->
            <ref></ref> <!-- must be counted -->
            <ref></ref> <!-- must be counted -->
            <ref></ref> <!-- must be counted -->
        </ref-list>
    </back>
</article>
```

**expected output file:**

```xml
<article>
    <front>
    <article-meta>
        <fpage>100</fpage> <!-- first page -->
        <lpage>117</lpage> <!-- last page -->
        <counts> <!-- this element must be created using XSLT -->
            <table-count count="1"/> <!-- should get the total number of <table-wrap> elements -->
            <ref-count count="5"/> <!-- should get the total number of <ref> elements -->
            <fig-count count="2"/> <!-- should get the total number of <fig> elements -->
            <eqs-count count="1"/> <!-- should get the total number of <disp-formula> elements -->
            <page-count count="17"/> <!-- should get the value of <lpage> minus <fpage> elements -->
        </counts>
    </article-meta>
    </front>
    <body>
        <table-wrap></table-wrap>
        <fig></fig>
        <fig></fig>
        <disp-formula></disp-formula>
    </body>
    <back>
        <ref-list>
            <ref></ref>
            <ref></ref>
            <ref></ref>
            <ref></ref>
            <ref></ref>
        </ref-list>
    </back>
</article>
```

Any idea how to do that??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <counts>
        <table-count count="{count(//table-wrap)}"/> <!-- total number of <table-wrap> elements -->
        <ref-count count="{count(//ref)}"/> <!-- total number of <ref> elements -->
        <fig-count count="{count(//fig)}"/> <!-- total number of <fig> elements -->
        <eqs-count count="{count(//disp-formula)}"/> <!-- total number of <disp-formula> elements -->
        <page-count count="{article/front/article-meta/lpage - article/front/article-meta/fpage}"/> <!-- the value of <lpage> minus <fpage> elements -->
    </counts>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Note: this counts the specified elements anywhere in the XML document, starting from the `/` root node. A more efficient way would specify the exact paths to the counted elements (the way it's done with the page count).

---

Edit:

To insert the counts immediately after after `<lpage>`, without making any other changes to the input, try:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="lpage">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
    <counts>
        <table-count count="{count(//table-wrap)}"/> <!-- total number of <table-wrap> elements -->
        <ref-count count="{count(//ref)}"/> <!-- total number of <ref> elements -->
        <fig-count count="{count(//fig)}"/> <!-- total number of <fig> elements -->
        <eqs-count count="{count(//disp-formula)}"/> <!-- total number of <disp-formula> elements -->
        <page-count count="{. - ../fpage}"/> <!-- the value of <lpage> minus <fpage> elements -->
    </counts>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: wow! that was fast, thanks! I will be able to try it an about 30 minutes. But how may I change it so that the `<counts>` element gets inserted exactly before the closing `</article-meta>`, or after the `</lpage>`?

Comment: @Luciano Is that the only change you need to make from input to output?

Comment: well yes..  Now I see that my question was badly written... I should have said: "how to insert a new element in a givem position.. (sorry)

Comment: I am trying to figure it out based on this ;-) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4887703/xslt-add-new-element-at-a-specific-location

Comment: It works! I still have some warnings but I think they are on my end. Also the pages element got the value of `NaN` instead of the integer..

Comment: @Luciano I have tested this with your sample input file, and received the expected output.

Comment: THANKS! You helped me A LOT. The issues I am having now are on my end.