# XSL cut text from one element and create new element [key | value] & paste this text inside value

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I am trying to do a cut and paste in XSL and i can not get it to work. I want to cut text from one element, and then create new element [key | value] and paste this text as value of given key.

Input xml looks like this

```
<root>
   <payload>blabla</payload>
   <metadata>
      <metadata-element>
          <key>some-key</key>
          <value>some-value</value>
      </metadata-element>
   </metadata>
</root>
```

and what i would like to achieve is something like this

```
<root>
   <payload></payload>
   <metadata>
      <metadata-element>
          <key>some-key</key>
          <value>some-value</value>
      </metadata-element>
   </metadata>
   <metadata>
       <metadata-element>
           <key>some-other-key</key>
           <value>blabla</value>
       </metadata-element>
   </metadata>
</root>
```

some-other-key

My XSL template looks like this

```
<axsl:template match="root/metadata">
  <axsl:copy>
     <axsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
     <metadata-element>
        <key>some-other-key</key>
        <value>
           <axsl:template match="root/payload">
              <axsl:copy>
                 <axs:apply-templates/>
              </axsl:copy>
        </value>
     </metadata-element>
  </axsl:copy>
```

Not huge fan of xsl... any help appreciated :) 
Thank you

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to add element to XML via XSL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21022309/how-to-add-element-to-xml-via-xsl)

Comment: You have asked the same question already: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21022309/how-to-add-element-to-xml-via-xsl/21023556#21023556.

Comment: @MathiasMüller the other questions was to create an element with the value based on the test output, now i would like to know how can i copy some text from one element and create new element ( same structure as previous question ) and paste that text into the value of the block

Comment: No matter how you bend the words, that's the same essentially. Instead of posting lots of questions, you could look at a basic introduction to XSLT. What do you think?

Comment: @MathiasMüller well i have been looking at XSL for few days now, and to be honest it feels like black magic to me, not structured not linear etc, + its quite complicated :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you see a problem like this, your first thought should really be to use the XSLT Identity Template (It's possible you are already using this in your XSLT, but you haven't shown a complete sample of your XSLT)

```
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
   <xsl:copy>
     <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

This means you only need to write matching templates for nodes you intend to change. You should view your "cut and paste" as two separate changes. The first change is to remove the text from the **payload** element, the second change is to add a new child element to the **root** element.

To change the **payload** element, you could write a template like this

```
<xsl:template match="payload">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

This copies the element, and its attributes only, thus ignoring the text (remember, text nodes are child nodes of elements).

Better still, instead of this, just write a template to ignore the text node under the **payload** element

```
<xsl:template match="payload/text()" />
```

For the second change, you are adding a new child to the **root** element (presumably only when a **payload** element is present. So, your template match would look like this

```
<xsl:template match="root[payload != '']">
```

Then, it is simply a case of having a modification of the identity template, but with extra code to explicitly add your new child (and all its descendants)

```
<xsl:copy>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
  <metadata>
    <metadata-element>
      <key>some-other-key</key>
      <value><xsl:value-of select="payload" /></value>
    </metadata-element>
  </metadata>
</xsl:copy>
```

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="payload/text()" />

  <xsl:template match="root[payload != '']">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
      <metadata>
        <metadata-element>
          <key>some-other-key</key>
          <value><xsl:value-of select="payload" /></value>
        </metadata-element>
      </metadata>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Actually, since `<payload>` is a sibling of the new `<metadata>` element, you could do it all within a single template matching "payload".

Comment: @Tim C. Thank you for this XSLT, i have tried to use it, in mine XSL as well as on its own however it doesn't seem to work :(, Also +1 for nice explenation :)

Comment: Can you be more precise when you say "it doesn't seem to work"? Are you getting an error? No output? A different output? I tested it at http://www.xmlplayground.com/XVYDzC and it seems to work for me. Also, if your XML sample correct? It would not work if you were actually using namespaces, for example.

Comment: @TimC yes i have tested it with oxygen and it works fine, therefore one of the services i am using must be doing something wrong :)

Comment: @TimC just one more thing, how can i modify this xslt to be valid for xml that uses namespaces ?? or is it even possible ?

Comment: In XSLT 2.0, you can use a `*` as a prefix to denote any namespace, so instead of writing "payload" in the xpath expression, you would write "*:payload", for example