# How to use awk to insert multiple lines after first match of a pattern, in multiple files

Tags: xml, linux, bash, awk, sed

I have a directory containing many subdirectories, each containing a `config.xml` file I want to edit. Like:

```
../jobs/foo_bar-v1.2_west/config.xml
../jobs/foo_bar-v1.3_west/config.xml
../jobs/foo_stuff-v1.3_east/config.xml
../jobs/foo_foo-v9.8_north/config.xml
../jobs/NOT_FOO-v0.1_whatev/config.xml
etc.
```

I need a way to insert multiple lines of text into several of the `../jobs/foo*/config.xml`  files, after matching the first instance of a specific line, `<properties>`.

Text to insert looks like:

```
    <a.bunch.of.TextGoesHere>
      <permission>one.foo.Items.Foo:person.name</permission>
      <permission>two.foo.Items.Foo:person.name</permission>
      <permission>three.foo.Items.Foo:person.name</permission>
    </a.bunch.of.TextGoesHere>
```

Each `../jobs/foo*/config.xml` looks like:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<foo1>
  <actions/>
  <description>foo2</description>
  <keepDependencies>false</keepDependencies>
  <properties>
    <foo3/>
  </properties>
 ...
  <lots_of_other_stuff>
  <properties>
    <junk>
  </properties>
```

Final output for each `config.xml` should look like:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<foo1>
  <actions/>
  <description>foo2</description>
  <keepDependencies>false</keepDependencies>
  <properties>
    <a.bunch.of.TextGoesHere>
      <permission>one.foo.Items.Foo:person.name</permission>
      <permission>two.foo.Items.Foo:person.name</permission>
      <permission>three.foo.Items.Foo:person.name</permission>
    </a.bunch.of.TextGoesHere>
    <foo3/>
  </properties>
 ...
  <lots_of_other_stuff>
  <properties>
    <junk>
  </properties>
```

I've tried using `sed` to insert after a specific line, like

```
#!/bin/bash
find ../jobs/run* -name config.xml -exec sed -i '6a\
<text to insert>' {} \;
```

but occasionally, long `<description>` text from the `config.xml` results in an unpredictable line number on which to insert.

Next I tried using `sed` to search for the first instance of `<properties>` and inserting after, like

```
sed -i '0,/properties/a test' config.xml
```

but this resulted in adding the `test` test after EVERY line until `<properties>` was found. Using `sed -i '1,/` had similar results. It was ugly.

I'm unsure if I'm using `sed` properly on this Amazon Linux box, and am thinking `awk` might work better here. Can anyone assist? Thanks.

Comment: I'd stongly recomment XSLT to edit XML. See this duplicate q: https://stackoverflow.com/q/3649195/7552

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the text to insert is in a file called `insert`:

```
sed -e '0,/<properties>/{/<properties>/r insert' -e '}' config.xml
```

The `r` command reads a file and appends it after the current line; the

```
0,/pattern/{/pattern/r filename}
```

makes sure that only the first instance of `pattern` gets the text appended. Because the command has to end after the filename read by `r`, it has to be split into two parts using `-e`.

To edit the files in-place, use `sed -i` (for GNU sed).

To do this for multiple files, you could use `find`:

```
find jobs -name 'config.xml' \
    -exec sed -i -e '0,/<properties>/{/<properties>/r insert' -e '}' {} +
```

This requires that the `insert` file is in the directory from which you run this command.

---

Your commands seemed almost correct, except that you didn't nest a second address into your range to make sure the appending happened just once.

Comment: Oh yeah, much nicer with auto-print.  Process until first match, act only on the matched line, pass the rest through as is. I'd probably still opt for `a` to not have a need for an extra file.

Comment: @OndrejK. Yeah, `a` or `r` might be more convenient, depending on how the the text to be inserted is provided.

Comment: Thank you, @BenjaminW., this worked pretty much perfectly without much altering. The script ended up looking like: `find ../jobs/foo* -name 'config.xml' -exec sed -i -e '0,/<properties>/{/<properties>/r insert.txt' -e '}' '{}' \;`
I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 1):

With GNU awk for inplace editing all you need is:

```
awk -i inplace '
NR==FNR { text = (NR>1 ? text ORS : "") $0 }
FNR==1 { cnt=0 }
{ print }
/<properties>/ && !cnt++ { print text }
' file_containing_text_to_insert ../jobs/foo*/config.xml
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This almost works. Unfortunately, it takes the contents of `file_containing_text_to_insert` and inserts it: A) Once at the very top of the file, and B) Once, above, EVERY instance of <properties>. Also, it just prints the output to my terminal and doesn't save the output to each file.

Comment: I forgot to add the `-i inplace` flag and I had the print in the wrong place and I didn't notice you only wanted the new text added after the **first** occurrence of properties in each file. Please try it again now.

Answer (score 1):

Following up on my comment with an answer:

The input xml file "file.xml"

```xml
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<foo1>
  <actions/>
  <description>foo2</description>
  <keepDependencies>false</keepDependencies>
  <properties>
    <foo3/>
  </properties>
 ...
  <lots_of_other_stuff />
  <properties>
    <junk />
  </properties>
</foo1>
```

The xslt stylesheet "file.xslt"

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <!-- Identity transform -->
    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <!-- insert the new stuff before the first child of the first properties element -->
    <xsl:template match="/foo1/properties[1]/*[1]">
        <a.bunch.of.TextGoesHere>
            <permission>one.foo.Items.Foo:person.name</permission>
            <permission>two.foo.Items.Foo:person.name</permission>
            <permission>three.foo.Items.Foo:person.name</permission>
        </a.bunch.of.TextGoesHere>
        <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The result, using [xmlstarlet](/questions/tagged/xmlstarlet)

```
$ xmlstarlet transform file.xslt file.xml 
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<foo1>
  <actions/>
  <description>foo2</description>
  <keepDependencies>false</keepDependencies>
  <properties>
    <a.bunch.of.TextGoesHere><permission>one.foo.Items.Foo:person.name</permission><permission>two.foo.Items.Foo:person.name</permission><permission>three.foo.Items.Foo:person.name</permission></a.bunch.of.TextGoesHere><foo3/>
  </properties>
 ...
  <lots_of_other_stuff/>
  <properties>
    <junk/>
  </properties>
</foo1>
```

---

To apply to all your files:

```
find . -name config.xml -exec sh -c '
    for xmlfile; do
        xmlstarlet transform xform.xslt "$xmlfile" > "$xmlfile".new &&
        ln "$xmlfile" "$xmlfile".bak &&
        mv "$xmlfile".new "$xmlfile"
    done
' sh {} +
```

Comment: I'm not sure what xmlstarlet is doing with the formatting of that output.

Comment: I appreciate your response, but I ended up using Benjamin W.'s sed line above. I wanted to avoid installing xmlstarlet or anything else on the box I'm working on.