# How to add multiple lines of code to multiple xml files using a Windows-based solution

Tags: xml, windows, batch-processing, edit, musicxml

I have hundreds of .xml files in a single directory, and I want to automatically add the same three lines of code to every file.

In each file, after the first instance of this line:

```
            </staff-details>
```

I want to add these lines:

```
            <transpose>
                <chromatic>-2</chromatic>
            </transpose>
```

The string `</staff-details>` appears multiple times in each file, but I only want to insert the three lines after the **first** time the string appears.

Please could someone tell me how to do this with a Windows utility (command-line is fine)?

I've found various similar questions here, but I haven't managed to make any of the answers work for this situation (which is no doubt because I am a novice at this kind of thing).

Thanks!

Comment: is   </staff-details> in the file more than once?

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured out a way to do this using Sed, by adapting the code from this post: [How to use awk to insert multiple lines after first match of a pattern, in multiple files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51048454/how-to-use-awk-to-insert-multiple-lines-after-first-match-of-a-pattern-in-multi)

I saved the lines I wanted to add to a file named **insert** – saved in the same directory as the XML files – and then ran the following Sed command in that directory:

`sed -i -e "0,/<\/staff-details>/{/<\/staff-details>/r insert" -e "}" *.xml`