# Inserting new line in txt file using CygWin

Tags: xml, unix, awk, sed, cygwin

I've got an XML table with the rows structured as follows:

```
<row>
    <C1>foobar</C1>
    <C2>foobar</C2>
    <C3>foobar</C3>
    <C4>foobar</C4>
    <C5>foobar</C5>
    <C6>foobar</C6>
    <C7>foobar</C7>
    <C8>foobar</C8>
    <C9>foobar</C9>
    <C10>foobar</C10>
    <C11>foobar</C11>
    <C12>foobar</C12>
</row>
```

What I would like to do is add a 13th column following the 12th, which needs to have an incremental number as its value to act as a primary key (starting from 1 and increasing by 1 per row, like X++ or etc). Worth noting is that there's about 20 million rows.

I have been trying to go about this using CygWin (Mintty), but I have absolutely no experience with it or anything Unix for that matter, it was simply the first thing I was recommended which was actually capable of loading these monstrous XML files.

For starters, I've tried using **Sed** to insert the 13th column using the following command:

```
-i -e 's/\/C12>/\/C12><C13><\/C13>/g' t1s.txt
```

My thought being that I'd replace the closing C12 bracket with itself + the 13th column. Instead it just replaced C12 with C13, as if the slashes hadn't been properly escaped.

There's probably a command to "insert" instead of "replace" which makes what I'm trying to do, look like complete madness, but I have no idea what that command would be and haven't had much luck searching. The closest I have come would be to use AWK instead, which I am up for, if this isn't feasible with Sed, but I have no clue how and it seems a tad harder as well.

What I hope to achieve is to change the document as follows (**This is long, but apparently it didn't make sense without including everything. This question only concerns how to add the 13th column in each row, the other 12 are just context**):

```
<row>
    <C1>foobar</C1>
    <C2>foobar</C2>
    <C3>foobar</C3>
    <C4>foobar</C4>
    <C5>foobar</C5>
    <C6>foobar</C6>
    <C7>foobar</C7>
    <C8>foobar</C8>
    <C9>foobar</C9>
    <C10>foobar</C10>
    <C11>foobar</C11>
    <C12>foobar</C12>
    <C13>1</C13>
</row>
<row>
    <C1>foobar</C1>
    <C2>foobar</C2>
    <C3>foobar</C3>
    <C4>foobar</C4>
    <C5>foobar</C5>
    <C6>foobar</C6>
    <C7>foobar</C7>
    <C8>foobar</C8>
    <C9>foobar</C9>
    <C10>foobar</C10>
    <C11>foobar</C11>
    <C12>foobar</C12>
    <C13>2</C13>
</row>
<row>
    <C1>foobar</C1>
    <C2>foobar</C2>
    <C3>foobar</C3>
    <C4>foobar</C4>
    <C5>foobar</C5>
    <C6>foobar</C6>
    <C7>foobar</C7>
    <C8>foobar</C8>
    <C9>foobar</C9>
    <C10>foobar</C10>
    <C11>foobar</C11>
    <C12>foobar</C12>
    <C13>3</C13>
</row>
<row>
    <C1>foobar</C1>
    <C2>foobar</C2>
    <C3>foobar</C3>
    <C4>foobar</C4>
    <C5>foobar</C5>
    <C6>foobar</C6>
    <C7>foobar</C7>
    <C8>foobar</C8>
    <C9>foobar</C9>
    <C10>foobar</C10>
    <C11>foobar</C11>
    <C12>foobar</C12>
    <C13>4</C13>
</row>
<row>
    <C1>foobar</C1>
    <C2>foobar</C2>
    <C3>foobar</C3>
    <C4>foobar</C4>
    <C5>foobar</C5>
    <C6>foobar</C6>
    <C7>foobar</C7>
    <C8>foobar</C8>
    <C9>foobar</C9>
    <C10>foobar</C10>
    <C11>foobar</C11>
    <C12>foobar</C12>
    <C13>5</C13>
</row>
<row>
    <C1>foobar</C1>
    <C2>foobar</C2>
    <C3>foobar</C3>
    <C4>foobar</C4>
    <C5>foobar</C5>
    <C6>foobar</C6>
    <C7>foobar</C7>
    <C8>foobar</C8>
    <C9>foobar</C9>
    <C10>foobar</C10>
    <C11>foobar</C11>
    <C12>foobar</C12>
    <C13>6</C13>
</row>
```

This goes on for several million rows...

Please note that the ONLY change is the addition of the 13th column and its value increasing for every row. That's ALL this question is about, the other 12 columns are just the surrounding structure.

Comment: Actually it's to show that there are 12 collumns that are all completely irrelevant to this question. I only want to add the 13th collumn, and this question only concerns that collumn. I will try to edit the question to reflect this.

Comment: @Ed Morton There, I edited the example to show all of the collumns. It's pretty massive now, but I hope it makes more sense. Please note once again that the first 12 collumns in every row aren't part of the question, and that the data that they contain is NOT IMPORTANT TO THE QUESTION, which is why I wrote "foobar" in their value.

Comment: Does it make sense now? I'm not exactly certain which part of this was unclear to begin with. I'm just trying to insert a collumn in an XML table and assign its value. I'd consider that to be extremely basic, conceptually, at least.

Comment: The post literally says "with the rows structured as follows" on the first line, which implies that this is an example of one of the 20 million rows, each of which I need to change by adding another collumn. I included the 12 foobar rows in case someone writes a script or etc that takes line numbers, indentation, and etc into account. Also, It sounds to me like you're contradicting yourself here. You're saying that I should cut off some of the collumns, yet accuse me of not defining the input/output exactly as expected. I literally have nothing else to add to either input or output.

Comment: As for the second one... the output. The first line below it literally says "This goes on for several million rows". So 6 is just a random number because I obviously can't post 20 million of them, yet I was told that the concept of the "counter" in the 13th row was hard to visualize (which I also don't understand, as I made clear that it was a primary key, and that's pretty much how they all look), so I showed it counting to 6. Could have been 4. Could have been 11.673.201. It doesn't matter, I showed where I wanted the 13th row to appear and how I wanted it's value to be assigned.

Comment: Sounds like you're happy with the response you got to your question and would rather not get feedback on why only 1 person responded or advice on how to get more/alternative solutions so I've just deleted my comments. If you change your mind then see [ask] and pay particular attention to the part about creating a [mcve] but either way - all the best!

Comment: Honestly, I find your feedback to be completely off. I'd love to take it to heart and improve upon it, but there's just nothing that I can change. I provided an example of a single row and left out the unimportant (and confidential) values. That's as minimal as it gets. It's also complete, seeing how this is litterally all there is to it. "I want to add a line at this point, 20 million times, and have it count each time" = Primary key. It does not get more minimal than that, and if you think it's incomplete, I can't for the life of me understand why. This is a basic database concept.

Comment: OK, last try - you provided 1 bock of 12 foobar rows as input. That is **not minimal** - to demonstrate multiple of anything all you need is 2 or 3 of that thing, not 12. Your input contains 1 block while your output is 6 blocks. Assuming you don't want to generate 6 output blocks from every input block (if you do then clarify that in your question) then the output you posted cannot be generated from the input you posted and so that would make your example **incomplete** and **not verifiable**. That is 3 strikes against it being a [mcve] - it's neither Minimal, nor Complete, nor Verifiable.

Comment: If your example had, say, 3 or 4 blocks of 2 or 3 foobars at a time and so did your output have that but modified exactly as you need a tool to modify that input (assuming that is what you're trying to convey) then you'd have provided a [mcve] and you'd have had multiple answers from multiple people by now.

Comment: I added an answer using my own [mcve] so you can see exactly what I'm talking about. Obviously I'm not sure if what I provided is actually representative of what you're trying to do, it's just my best guess.

Comment: The reason I included all 12 collumns in the example was exactly to avoid problems that could arise from it being incomplete, such as solutions that depend on the exact layout that was presented, so I presented the actual layout of a row. As the page you keep linking says: "don't sacrifice communication to brevity". That was my reasoning when typing that out, that someone might miss it if I shortened it. It's easier to see a structure than to visualize it based on a description of how it was shortened, which was something that I did actually contemplate doing.

Comment: So if you'd had 100 columns per row in your real data then your example for us to read/understand would have included 100 columns? Using 2 or 3 columns instead of 12 (or 100) is not sacrificing communication to brevity, it's simply coming up with a minimal example that demonstrates your problem. Posting 1 block of input but 6 blocks of output **is** sacrificing communication to brevity. Always have your output be exactly what you want generated from your input, and if you have 1 of something in the real data then show 1 in the example, and if it's more than 1 in the input then show 2 or 3.

Comment: As for the output. It wasn't even there originally. The concept of wanting to add the 13th collumn underneath the existing 12 in the example seemed simple enough. It was also quite clear from the text that the row was an example out of about 20 million, and that the solution had to apply to all of the rows. The output was made to include 6 examples to highlight how these rows repeat in the actual document, and to show how where exactly the incrementing value was used and how it acted, as oliv was unsure of that. Originally the output was shortened, which was undone in an attempt to comply here

Comment: Providing no output is just as bad as providing output that can't be generated from the input. What you need to provide in your example to get the most/best answers to your question is extremely simple - minimal input that demonstrates your problem and exactly the output you want to get from that input. That's what makes it easiest for us to understand your needs and the less of our extremely valuable time that we're donating for free to help you we have to spend trying to understand your question the better chance you'll get answers.

Comment: No, but in that case I'd probably have shown the first 2 then made a sort of "gap" and shown 99 and 100, to indicate that it continues between them. Could have done that here too, considered doing it, decided against it because 12 was within what I deemed "not indecently lengthy".

Comment: Adding any sort of a gap is bad. We need something we can copy/paste from your question onto our file system so we can run a possible solution against the input you provided to see if it generates the expected output you provided. We should be able to do a `diff` of a file containing the output the tool generates given your provided input against a file containing the output you provided and it that reports no differences then the tool works, otherwise it doesn't. It's that simple. Having `...`s or other gaps in the input or output means we can't do that and so makes the example unverifiable.

Comment: Okay, but I was working under the premise that I was not aware of whether or not the solutions that I was going to be presented with were going to rely on the amount of lines or etc. If I had given an example with 3 collumns instead, what would I have named them? 1,2,3? In that case the offered solution would be creating the 4th collumn. Again, at best this would be changing a "4" to a "13", at worst, I'd have to alter line dependant code to account for the difference. I wasn't sure if that might be a risk, so I eliminated it to be on the safe side.

Comment: Yes, you'd have named them 1, 2, 3 or whatever else you liked and it's not a bad thing if you have to tweak the solution you get to a simple example to work for your real world data, just as long as you can see how to make that change. If you can't then you just ask a followup question, no big deal. See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51902351/1745001) for what I think might be an example of a [mcve] that demonstrates your problem.

Comment: The thing is that I was uncertain how major said "tweak" would be. Since I am working out of a command prompt here (whereas everything I've previously done is text files), the role that lines would have in this question was completely uncertain to me. I wasn't sure if the solution would be altered dramatically by it or not. In this case, the tweaking is literally just changing a few characters, but as far as I knew, I could have ended up with a completely useless solution because it applied to a different file structure.

Comment: But you wouldn't have accepted a solution like that, you'd have got multiple answers and just accepted a solution that **was** easy to tweak. Any code that behaves radically differently for 12 lines vs 2 or 3 lines is clearly/obviously just very bad code. Anyway - now you know....

Comment: I don't get the philosophy behind this reasoning. How is the possibility of several people wasting time typing out unusable answers and then spending even more time addressing followup questions a better scenario than having 10 useless tiny lines that can easily be "glossed over" in seconds? Is there something that I am not understanding correctly? Thanks for the answer by the way. Picking it because it took me literally 30 seconds to successfully test, whereas the other one took me 15 minutes to learn how to install (with help).

Comment: To the edit: Yeah, it's bad code because it's other solutions are possible. But I didn't know if that would be the case either. This whole discussion centers on me knowing absolutely nothing about the given environment and choosing to approach it with no assumptions as a result.

Comment: No-one's actually going to look at a question that says "in my real data I have 12 columns, here's a MCVE with 3.." and post a solution that depends on there being 3 columns. If they did then they will get responses to help them not do that again so they will benefit from the experience. How is what I suggested better: look at the results you got trying it your way - out of the hundreds of people who read your question you got 1 person responding with a solution you don't want to use. The FAQs [ask] and [mcve] are there to help you get answers, not to mislead you into wasting anyone's time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if your input is really that regular and simple then chances are all you need is:

```
awk '{print} sub(/<C12>.*/,""){print $0"<C13>"++cnt"</C13>"}' file
```

but without something concrete to test against its a guess. Here's that doing what I **think** you are trying to do using a MCVE with 2 foobars per block instead of 12:

```
$ cat file
<row>
    <C1>foobar</C1>
    <C2>foobar</C2>
</row>
<row>
    <C1>foobar</C1>
    <C2>foobar</C2>
</row>
<row>
    <C1>foobar</C1>
    <C2>foobar</C2>
</row>

$ awk '{print} sub(/<C2>.*/,""){print $0"<C3>"++cnt"</C3>"}' file
<row>
    <C1>foobar</C1>
    <C2>foobar</C2>
    <C3>1</C3>
</row>
<row>
    <C1>foobar</C1>
    <C2>foobar</C2>
    <C3>2</C3>
</row>
<row>
    <C1>foobar</C1>
    <C2>foobar</C2>
    <C3>3</C3>
</row>
```

Note that the numbers 12 and 13 can with a tweak be generated from your input, they don't need top be hard-coded in the script, but idk if that's necessary or not so I didn't bother doing it.

Comment: This is exactly what I am trying to do, and it is in fact that simple. Your solution is a lot simpler than the current one, so I will give it a spin. Also, I am fully aware that the amount of collumns isn't important in this solution, but I wasn't sure that this would be the case when I asked the question, that's why all 12 were there.

Comment: There's what you state in the question text "My real input has 12 columns..." and the [mcve] you provide for us to test against "Here's a MCVE with 2 columns...". They do not have to be identical to get a good solution - just differentiate 1 instance from more-than-1 instances in the example by providing 2 or 3 instances in the more-than-1 case and state in the text what your real "more-than-1" value is.

Comment: Alright. Will approach it like that from now on. Having spent several years on the internet though, I will not be surprised if I one day encounter someone criticizing me with the exact opposite standpoint. Alas, you came through with the best possible solution I could have hoped for, so I will regard your viewpoint on question structure accordingly.

Comment: By the way, is there a way that I can alter this solution to make it write this change into the file instead of printing it in the console?

Comment: As with any UNIX command just add `> output` to the end, i.e. `awk 'script' input > output`. If you want to update the original file then `awk 'script' input > output && mv output input`. GNU awk alternatively has a `-i inplace` option like GNU seds `-i` if you care.

Comment: Yes. For any UNIX command `cmd`, you can do `cmd > output` to save it's output.

Comment: Okay, will go with the output file then. That makes it easier to test out on the actual files. Thanks again for the effort and patience. I will consider this a learning experience in multiple ways.

Comment: wrt `I will not be surprised if I one day encounter someone criticizing me with the exact opposite standpoint.` - if you do what the forum FAQ [ask] tells you to do then they can't criticize you for doing so. I'm not saying you will never get asked to modify or provide more info or something but the goal is always simply to follow [ask] and provide a [mcve] and you can't go wrong doing that.

Answer (score 2):

Using `xmlstarlet` and XSLT transform:

Given this XSLT file

```
$ cat f.xslt 
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <!-- Identity transform -->
    <xsl:template match="/ | @* | node()">
            <xsl:copy>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
            </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="/">
            <xsl:for-each select="/doc/row">
                    <xsl:copy>
                            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
                            <C13><xsl:value-of select="position()"/></C13>
                    </xsl:copy>
            </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

And assuming the `<row>...</row>` are enclosed within the tag `<doc>...</doc>`, you can add the `C13` node with its counting number by using this command:

```
xmlstarlet tr f.xslt file
```

`tr` means "transpose" and uses an XSLT file to modify the given `file`.

The XSLT mainly contains 2 blocks.
One called the "identity" that acually leave the input as is. The second block looks for each `<doc><row>` and copies its content and add the `<C13>` node with the counting number.

Credits: [here](https://peterstuifzand.nl/2016/03/16/rewrite-xml-with-xmlstarlet.html) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3649195/adding-element-in-middle-of-xml-using-xslt)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The rows are not enclosed in doc tags, they are however enclosed in a table tag. To clarify, the entire document structure is a declaration line on top and then a table tag containing all of the rows. That's about it though. Is it possible to apply this solution in a way that accomodates this?

Comment: @Noobie Just replace the `doc` in the line `<xsl:for-each select="/doc/row">` with the tag name that encloses the `<row>` in your XML file.

Comment: Alright, will this work if they are all enclosed in the same tag/parent, or do they need to have a different parent each? Might be a dumb question but I just wanna be sure. :) Thanks so much for your efforts by the way.

Comment: @Noobie As far as I know, a valid XML file has a single root tag (for example HTML document and the `<html>...</html>` tag). So it must be in a single root tag. How deep the `<row>` is located doesn't matter as long as the `select` path is correct.

Comment: Alright, it appears that the table tag is the root tag then. Thanks, will work with that as my guideline. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

To edit an XML file, you'd better use an XML parser.

Here is the command to insert the node `C13` containing text `foobar` into your XML file using `xmlstarlet` (available in Cygwin):

```
xmlstarlet ed --subnode "/row" -t elem -n C13 -v foobar ts1.txt
```

- `ed`: Edit/Update XML document
- `--subnode "/row"`: add a node inside the `row` node
- `-t elem`: type is element
- `-n C13`: name is `C13`
- `v foobar`: value is `foobar`

Comment: can xmlstartlet add the incremental value in the rows as well? If so, how?

Comment: @Noobie What do you mean by _incremental value_? Please update your question with such an example.

Comment: Basically something like X++  if X starts at 1 and increases by 1 for each row it appears in, basically numbering the rows for use as primary key.

Comment: @Noobie This is likely possible by using a combination of `xmlstarlet` and bash statement. But I don't know if you mean to increase the node name, its value or other `<row>` node... Please update your question with a meaningful example.

Comment: The value. I've tried summing up the desired result. Does this make sense?