# Use xslt to add <fo:table-column> to XML

Tags: xml, pdf, xslt, xsl-fo

I need to render PDFs using xml files.
For some reasons The PDF engine does not work very well with tables that the width are specified by percentage.

This is the source html

```
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td style="width:60%;">foo</td>
            <td style="width:40%;">bla</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>foo</td>
            <td>bla</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

With the existing xslt it is converted to xml 1:

```
<fo:table>  
 <fo:table-header>
        <fo:table-row>
            <fo:table-cell width="60%">
                fool
            </fo:table-cell>
            <fo:table-cell width="40%">
               bla
            </fo:table-cell>
        </fo:table-row>
    </fo:table-header>
    <fo:table-body>
        <fo:table-row>
            <fo:table-cell>
                foo
            </fo:table-cell>
            <fo:table-cell>
               bla
            </fo:table-cell>
        </fo:table-row>
    </fo:table-body>
</fo:table>
```

PDF table using the above xml will be not be divided as 60% 40%.

However, the following is OK

xml 2

```
<fo:table>
    <fo:table-column column-width="60%"/>
    <fo:table-column column-width="40%"/>
 <fo:table-header>
        <fo:table-row>
            <fo:table-cell width="60%">
                foo
            </fo:table-cell>
            <fo:table-cell width="40%">
               bla
            </fo:table-cell>
        </fo:table-row>
    </fo:table-header>
    <fo:table-body>
        <fo:table-row>
            <fo:table-cell
                foo
            </fo:table-cell>
            <fo:table-cell>
               bla
            </fo:table-cell>
        </fo:table-row>
    </fo:table-body>
</fo:table>
```

So the question is, given the source html, how to use xslt to add `<fo:table-column>` element beneath the `<fo:table>` element, using the corresponding `<fo:table-cell width=` value? Ideally there should not be duplicate `<fo:table-column>` if xml 1 has multiple `<fo:table-row>`.

I just need to add the extra `<fo:table-column>` becasue the other conversion are being done.

I have looked at some similar questions but still got no solution
[Adding element in middle of xml using xslt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3649195/adding-element-in-middle-of-xml-using-xslt/3649513)

My current apporach:

```
    <xsl:template match="html:table">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:for-each select=".//html:tr[html:td/@style][1]/html:td">
                <xsl:if test="contains(@style,'width')">
                    <fo:table-column>
                        <xsl:attribute name="column-width">
                            <xsl:value-of select="substring-after(substring-before(@style, ';'),'width:')"/>
                        </xsl:attribute>
                    </fo:table-column>
                </xsl:if>
            </xsl:for-each>
     </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
```

It is not working because the `<fo:table-column>` is not added beneath the original `<fo-table` but instead a new `<fo-table>` is created and the  `<fo:table-column>` is added there

Answer (score 1):

This will take your first table row with some width data and use it for your output.

```
<xsl:template match="@* | *">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | * | text()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="fo:table">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:for-each select=".//fo:table-row[fo:table-cell/@width][1]/fo:table-cell">
            <fo:table-column>
                <xsl:attribute name="column-width" select="@width"/>
            </fo:table-column>
        </xsl:for-each>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | *"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Sorry I did not ask the question I really meant to ask, I just have it mofidied...

Comment: I see the modification, but your posted code just prints an empty new <fo:table> and unless you don't use xsl:next-match or apply-template there, there should be no entries beneath it. Your code seems right though, there is just an apply-templates missing. If you want more help, please share more code or update your results above, so your xslt matches the result.