# How to insert an app.config section or change it if it is already there

Tags: xml, xslt, app-config

I have the following simplified app.config file of a .NET 4.7 application:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
   <startup>
      <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2"/>
   </startup>
   <runtime>
   </runtime>
</configuration>
```

Now, I need to insert a new section (element) named `Dependencies` into it if that section does not exist yet. That section needs to have a child element named `MyDependencies` which can contain several `CustomDependency` elements. Here's an example:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
   <startup>
      <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2"/>
   </startup>
   <Dependencies>
      <MyDependencies>
         <CustomDependency Name="UniqueName" Id="12345678-1234-1234-1234-123456781234" AnotherAttribute="CustomValue"/>
      </MyDependencies>
   </Dependencies>
   <runtime>
   </runtime>
</configuration>
```

However, if the `CustomDependency` element with a specific name is already there, the values of the attributes of that element (`Id` and `AnotherAttribute`) just need to be changed. This should be done by using parameters that are submitted to the XSLT file.

So, the input might look like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
   <startup>
      <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2"/>
   </startup>
   <Dependencies>
      <MyDependencies>
        <CustomDependency Name="UniqueName" Id="ABC45678-1234-1234-1234-123456781234" AnotherAttribute="WrongValue"/>
        <CustomDependency Name="UniqueName2" Id="87654321-1234-1234-1234-123456781234" AnotherAttribute="CustomValue2"/>
      </MyDependencies>
      <YourDependencies>
        <CustomDependency Name="UniqueName2" Id="ABC54321-1234-1234-1234-123456781234" AnotherAttribute="CustomValue2"/>
      </YourDependencies>
   </Dependencies>
   <runtime>
   </runtime>
</configuration>
```

in which case the attribute values of the element with the name `UniqueName`, e.g.

```xml
<CustomDependency Name="UniqueName" Id="ABC45678-1234-1234-1234-123456781234" AnotherAttribute="WrongValue"/>
```

have to be updated to

```xml
<CustomDependency Name="UniqueName" Id="12345678-1234-1234-1234-123456781234" AnotherAttribute="CustomValue"/>
```

How would the XSLT code need to look like to make this happen?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Adding element in middle of xml using xslt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3649195/adding-element-in-middle-of-xml-using-xslt)

Comment: Please post an example that shows both cases.

Comment: I tried to apply the answer of that question but my xslt knowhow is just not there at all and I couldn't make it work

Comment: @michael I clarified it a bit. It comes down to just changing the attribute values if the element is there and creating the element if it does not exist.

Comment: So where exactly are you stuck with this? Seems simple enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />
  
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()" name="copy-all">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="/configuration/Dependencies/MyDependencies/CustomDependency[@Name='UniqueName']/@Id">
    <xsl:attribute name="Id">CustomValue</xsl:attribute>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="/configuration/Dependencies/MyDependencies/CustomDependency[@Name='UniqueName']/@AnotherAttribute">
    <xsl:attribute name="AnotherAttribute">CustomValue</xsl:attribute>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="startup[not(../Dependencies)]">
    <xsl:call-template name="copy-all" />
    <xsl:element name="Dependencies">
      <xsl:element name="MyDependencies">
        <xsl:element name="CustomDependency">
          <xsl:attribute name="Name">UniqueName</xsl:attribute>
          <xsl:attribute name="Id">12345678-1234-1234-1234-123456781234</xsl:attribute>
          <xsl:attribute name="AnotherAttribute">CustomValue</xsl:attribute>  
        </xsl:element>
      </xsl:element>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```